# Pull a preference from a xml preference layout

Tags: preferences, save, android-preferences, sharedpreferences, user-preferences

Okay so i have been working on this for a while now, i know this has got to be easier than im making it but what im trying to do is i have my xml preference layout or whatever you would like to call it, on that layout i have several check boxes a list view item and an edit text, what i need to do is get those preferences from the xml layout, then i need to store them and read them in another activity. I have worked a little with these however i always had an activity that stored the strings then i extended that activity within the the activity i need the preferences for. I know there are hundreds of these tutorials all over the internet but i just dont understand how to implement them. Heres my code so far.

```
  public class MyPreference extends PreferenceActivity 
{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.random_pref);

  // Get the custom preference
  final Preference randomPref = (Preference) findPreference("randomPref");
  Preference randomDayPref = (Preference) findPreference("randomDayPref");
  Preference hourPref = (Preference) findPreference("hourPref");
  Preference maxRandomMessagePref = (Preference) findPreference("maxRandomMessagePref");
  Preference randomContactsPref = (Preference) findPreference("randomContactsPref");
  Preference sendSMSPref = (Preference) findPreference("sendSMSPref");
  Preference sendEmailPref = (Preference) findPreference("sendEmailPref");

  //Finished
  randomPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });

  //Finished
  randomDayPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });


  hourPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });


  maxRandomMessagePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });


  randomContactsPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });


  sendSMSPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });

  sendEmailPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
   {
    return true;
   }
  });
 }
}
```

And heres my XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Randomization Properties">
                <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:title="Random Delays"
                 android:summary="Message"
                 android:defaultValue="false"
                 android:key="randomPref" /> 
                <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:title="Throughout The Day"
                 android:summary="Message"
                 android:defaultValue="false"
                 android:key="randomDayPref" />
             <ListPreference
                    android:title="Random Hourly Timings"
                    android:summary="Message"
                    android:key="hourPref"
                    android:defaultValue="6"
                    android:entries="@array/hours"
                    android:entryValues="@array/listValues"/> 
                <EditTextPreference
                 android:name="Messages"
                 android:summary="Message"
                 android:defaultValue="100"
                 android:title="Messages"
                 android:key="maxRandomMessagePref" />
        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Contacts">       
                <Preference
                 android:title="@string/contacts"
                 android:summary="Message"
                 android:key="randomContactsPref" /> 
        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Options">         
                <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:title="Send Through SMS"
                 android:summary="Send Messages As Normal"
                 android:defaultValue="false"
                 android:key="sendSMSPref" /> 
                <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:title="Send Trhrough E-Mail"
                 android:summary="Send Messages Through E-Mail Uses E-Mail Settings"
                 android:defaultValue="false"
                 android:key="sendEmailPref" />          
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

from what i see online i may need to create an onPrefernceChangeListener()? i am really at a loss with this i know its got to be simple i just don't understand how to pull the preferences from the xml when a user changes them and then save them so my man activity can read them and adjust accordingly. If someone who knows what they are doing could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for here but I'll attempt to answer.

If you aren't doing anything fancy, you won't need to override any of the preference's `setOnPreferenceClickListener`s if you use the Default Shared Preferences.  The base class will handle saving it for you.

To access these preferences from another activity, you will do something like this:

```
SharedPreferences defaultSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean savedValue = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("randomPref", false);
```

Comment: If I am using my own preference file (not default shared), does it automatically save preferences? Or do I need to do that? If so, how can I do that inside `setOnPreferenceClickListener`?